# Query 2 tables correctly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables in my SQL database named 'Team' and 'TeamAlias'. The first tables holds the proper full names of some football teams, and the other hold abbreviated names. Both tables contain the TeamID that identifies the teams. When I import data to my database the data could contain the proper name or an alias. I need to query both tables to get the ID of both the home and away teams. The following code gives me the correct result when both team names are in the Team table or both are in the TeamAlias table:

```
INSERT INTO temp2 (TeamIDHome, TeamIDAway)
select HomeTeam.TeamID as TeamIDHome, AwayTeam.TeamID as TeamIDAway
from temp1 as U
join Team as HomeTeam on U.TeamNameHome = HomeTeam.TeamName
join Team as AwayTeam on U.TeamNameAway = AwayTeam.TeamName
UNION ALL
select HomeTeam.TeamID as TeamIDHome, AwayTeam.TeamID as TeamIDAway
from temp1 as U
join TeamAlias as HomeTeam on U.TeamNameHome = HomeTeam.TeamName
join TeamAlias as AwayTeam on U.TeamNameAway = AwayTeam.TeamName
```

My problem occurs when one team in is the Team table and the other is in the TeamAlias table. In that case no results are returned. I would appreciate some help to configure this query correctly.

Here are extracts from the tables that I am using:

temp1:

```
CompetitionID   DateKickOff             TimeKickOff         TeamIDHome  TeamIDAway  TeamNameHome    TeamNameAway    ScoreHome   ScoreAway
17              2013-08-10 00:00:00.000 13:31:00.0000000    NULL        NULL        Augsburg        Dortmund        0           4
```

temp2:

```
    TeamIDHome    TeamIDAway
    NULL          NULL
```

Team:

```
TeamID  TeamName                TeamLocation
139     Augsburg                Germany
140     Bayern Munich           Germany
141     Borussia Dortmund       Germany
142     Eintracht Braunschweig  Germany
143     Eintracht Frankfurt     Germany
```

TeamAlias:

```
 TeamID TeamName
 161    Duisburg
 162    FC Koln
 164    G Furth
 165    H Rostock
 141    Dortmund
```

The answer that I need should populate the NULL fields in table temp2 with values 139 and 141.

EDIT:
Final Solution was:

```
;WITH TeamInfo ( ID, Name, Alias ) 
AS (
    SELECT t.TeamID, t.TeamName, ta.TeamName
    FROM Team t
        FULL OUTER JOIN TeamAlias ta ON t.TeamID = ta.TeamID
)
INSERT INTO temp2 (TeamIDHome, TeamIDAway)
SELECT home.ID AS TeamIDHome, away.ID AS TeamIDAway
    FROM temp1 g
        INNER JOIN TeamInfo home ON g.TeamNameHome IN ( home.Name, home.Alias )
        INNER JOIN TeamInfo away ON g.TeamNameAway IN ( away.Name, away.Alias )
```

Comment: You need an [OUTER JOIN](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some slight assumptions, but you should be able to work it out from here :

```
CREATE TABLE #Team ( TeamID int, TeamName varchar(20) )
INSERT INTO #Team VALUES
    ( 1, 'Team Name 1' ), 
    ( 2, 'Team Name 2' ), 
    ( 3, 'Team Name 3' ) 

CREATE TABLE #TeamAlias ( TeamID int, TeamAlias varchar(20) )
INSERT INTO #TeamAlias VALUES 
    ( 1, 'T1' ), 
    ( 2, 'T2' ), 
    ( 3, 'T3' ) 

CREATE TABLE #Games ( GameID int, HomeTeam varchar(20), AwayTeam varchar(20) ) 
INSERT INTO #Games VALUES 
    ( 1, 'T1', 'T2' ), 
    ( 2, 'T2', 'Team Name 3' ), 
    ( 3, 'Team Name 3', 'Team Name 1' ) 


;WITH TeamInfo ( ID, Name, Alias ) 
AS (
    SELECT t.TeamID, t.TeamName, ta.TeamAlias
    FROM #Team t
        FULL OUTER JOIN #TeamAlias ta ON t.TeamID = ta.TeamID
)
SELECT g.GameID, home.ID AS TeamIDHome, away.ID AS TeamIDAway
    FROM #Games g
        INNER JOIN TeamInfo home ON g.HomeTeam IN ( home.Name, home.Alias )
        INNER JOIN TeamInfo away ON g.AwayTeam IN ( away.Name, away.Alias )
ORDER BY GameID
```

EDIT: Changed `TeamInfo` definition to `FULL OUTER JOIN` after question was updated....

Comment: Hi Shane. I've added sample tables to help. Note that there is not always an Alias. Augsburg only exists in the Team table in this example. Dortmund is in both but will only match in the TeamAlias table as that is where the name is the same as in table temp1. It would be great if you could rework your answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Shane. Got it working. I had to add the INSERT line half way through the code. I've put my final code in my question just to clarify the final answer to my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a union all, instead use the same joins above.. If you have posted the exact DDL and some sample DDL, I would have written the exact but this is based on assumptions but something like below should work fine.

```
select HomeTeam.TeamID as TeamIDHome, AwayTeam.TeamID as TeamIDAway
from temp1 as U
join Team as HomeTeam on U.TeamNameHome = HomeTeam.TeamName
join Team as AwayTeam on U.TeamNameAway = AwayTeam.TeamName
join TeamAlias as HomeTeamAlias on U.TeamNameHome = HomeTeam.TeamName
join TeamAlias as AwayTeamAlias on U.TeamNameAway = AwayTeam.TeamName
```

Comment: This returns nothing for me just like my query. I've added some samples of the tables to my question to help with answers.